# jsp request getParameter return null

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I have problem with this example:

```
<c:set value="${dataRap}" scope="request" var="dataDos"/>
            <%
                String dataDo = (String)request.getParameter("dataDos");
                request.setAttribute("dataDo",dataDo); 
                out.print(dataDo);
            %>
```

My questions:

1. Why I have null? ${dataRap} have value.
2. How use dataDostaw in jsp? ${dataDosaw}

Comment: how do you set the value for `${dataRap}` ? Are you getting any errors . check your browser console ?

Comment: <c:set value="2014-09-09" scope="request" var="dataRap"/> no errors

Comment: @Rawness basically your question not explain much detail here so please provide some extra info. where you want your variable in jsp or in any controller

Comment: Do u hv any value in datadao? Varaible.?show stack trace